# ItemLoader add_value method does not work on some fields

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy's ItemLoader in my project. The problem is that it works fine for some fields while it does nothing for other fields.

I am working with Scrapy 1.7.2 / Python 3.7 on ubuntu 16.04 server.

```
class RealtyItem(Item):
...
price_for_sale = Field(input_processor=MapCompose(drop_currency), output_processor=TakeFirst())  # int
    price = Field(input_processor=MapCompose(drop_currency), output_processor=TakeFirst())  # int
    price_without_tax = Field(input_processor=MapCompose(drop_currency), output_processor=TakeFirst())  # int
    price_per_unit = Field(input_processor=MapCompose(drop_currency), output_processor=TakeFirst())  # int
    supplementary_charges = Field(input_processor=MapCompose(drop_currency), output_processor=TakeFirst()) # int
...
```

So there are several fields which share the same processors.
While debugging, I can see that only `supplementary_charges` is processed and added to the item while other price fields is missing in the item. It looks like `item.add_value(label, value)` does nothing for 4 price fields out of 5. 
Here is my code:

```
    def parse_property(self, response):
        item = ItemLoader(item=RealtyItem(), response=response)

        details = response.xpath('//div[@class="flat-attributes__item"]')
        for record in details:
            label = record.xpath('./p[1]/text()').get().strip()
            if label not in self._ignore_fields:
                value = ''.join(record.xpath('./p[2]//text()').getall()).strip()
                if label in self._composite_fields:
                    for v in value.split(','):
                        l = self._property_title[v.strip()]
                        item.add_value(l, True)
                else:
                    label = self._property_title[label]
                    item.add_value(label, value)
```

Labels are taken from hardcoded dictionary:

```
 _property_title = {
        'Nebenkosten': 'supplementary_charges',
        'Bruttomiete (inkl. NK)': 'price',
        'Nettomiete (exkl. NK)': 'price_without_tax',
        'Fläche': 'living_space',
        'Balkon/Sitzplatz': 'balcony',
        'Anzahl Zimmer': 'rooms',
        'Aussicht': 'perspective',
        'Referenz': 'reference'
...
}
```

I'm pretty sure that all price values are being scraped properly:
[image: parse values]

But at the end all prices are missing in the item while `supplementary_charges` and other fields are in place:
[image: after parsing]

And if I debug it step by step,
I can clearly see that nothing is changes after `item.add_value` call.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have prices on the site in HTML code? Are you sure you use correct XPath?

Comment: yes, as you can see on the screenshots

Comment: Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve